# Angular strictly typed form - why don't I get current value from FormGroup.value.abc property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular15

I'm working on an Angular 15 app where I've created a strictly typed form. I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to use the `this.formData.value.firstName` convention to get the current value of the firstName control in a FormGroup. Instead, I'm getting a null. If, however, I use either of the conventions below, I get what is currently entered into the input control for the corresponding FormControl

```
this.formData.get('firstName').value // works
this.formData.controls.firstName.getRawValue() // works
```

I unfortunately had been using the `this.formData.get('firstName').value` style throughout my .ts file but then in my infinite wisdom thought that it would be better to use the more direct approach -- now finding that was a mistake and it looks like I need to put them all back. Just don't understand why!

BTW: I'm also using an interface that extends from FormGroup to house the definition of the FormGroup itself and I'm using the FormBuilder to setup `this.formData` -- not sure if either of those is relevant here.

```
export interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
}

export interface IPersonForm
    extends FormGroup<{
        firstName: FormControl<string|undefined>;
}> {}

...

externalData: IPerson;
formData!: IPersonForm;

...

this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: this.formBuilder.control(this.externalData?.firstName, Validators.required),
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I'm misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Edit: also worth noting, potentially, is that the area of the code where I'm trying to get the current value of the control, it's a method that's called when `this.formData.controls.firstName.valueChanges.subscribe((val)=>...)` is firing and if I `console.log('change', val)`, it has the value. I feel like there's some difference in how the strictly typed forms are handling the update to the FormControl values.

Edit 2: if I throw `{{formData.value.firstName}}` in my component's html file, it shows the value, not null...

Edit 3: same as above if I throw a button in the HTML where click logs the value: it's not null. And as a "fix", if I put `this.formData.updateValueAndValidity()` at the top of the method where I'm trying to get the current value of `this.formData.value.firstName`, it then does have what's in the input. I feel like this is a dirty hack though. In my (faulty?!?) reasoning, I could see how `getRawValue()` might return a "not fully persisted to the form" value, but I would then NOT expect `get('firstName')` to return something different than `.value.firstName`

Very basic example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uk3dfd?file=src/main.ts
If you type into the First Name field, there's html and console output that shows the various values and you should see that wherever formData.value.firstName is used, the output is always lagging and shows what it was before the change.

Comment: what do you see if you log `this.formData.values`?

Comment: @NathanT. there's no "values" property, just "value" which then has the props in the FormGroup -- it shows null for those values. ```this.formData.getRawValue()``` works similarly to ```this.formData.controls.firstName.getRawValue()``` in that it DOES show what's currently in the input for the firstName control

Comment: I indeed meant `value`. Still strange works fine for me. Could you provide a minimal stackblitz example?

Comment: @NathanT. I setup a stackblitz and referenced it in the OP

Comment: the issue of your value being one step behind is solved by calling the `this.formData.valueChanges ...` instead of the value changes of the specific control.

Comment: @NathanT. - thanks, indeed it does! This was a simple example, in my real world application, there are over 20 controls and I only want to do certain things for certain control changes so the ```this.formData.valueChanges``` doesn't really work for me. I guess what's happening here is that with the approach I was taking, the change hasn't propogated up to the FormGroup yet and accessing the value through ```this.formData.value.firstName``` is the FormGroup's understanding of what the value is, not the firstName FormControl itself?

Comment: @NathanT. and now with that understanding (right or wrong?!?), if I do ```this.formData.controls.firstName.value```, I get the value as the FormControl knows it, the ```this.formData.controls.firstName.getRawValue()``` wasn't doing anything special here.

If you want to put your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue of your value being one step behind is solved by calling the `this.formData.valueChanges` instead of `this.formData.controls['firstName'].valueChanges`

We think this is because the change hasn't propogated up to the FormGroup yet when the control `valueChanges` invokes.

What you could also do is use the `value` of your `valueChanges` to have access to the latest value.